# Updating to a new CSS file

Tags: css

I am wondering how I can add a border to all elements that a particular CSS file touches without adding it to every class, id, and element in that CSS file.

The idea is that I can take one class from an old CSS file and move it to a new CSS file and then mark it with a border so I know that it has been moved. I remember seeing a YouTube video a few years ago explaining this but I can't find it again.

Comment: I found the video I was talking about around the 16 minute mark. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvTryZjGyg8 It is not the solution that will work this time but it is a great technique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a style declaration in the new CSS file and append every class you migrate to that file there.

e.g.

```css
/* Will be removed after migration is finished */
.my-style-01,
.my-style-02,
.my-style-03 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

/* Below you can add all your styles from the old file one after the other */
.my-style-01 {}
/* ... */
```

This is not an "full automatic" solution but it works for keeping track of what has been migrated.